# How to create a script that runs yum as root, but rest of script as calling user

Tags: bash, sudo, users

I have a bash script that uses yum to install some Docker-related utilities, and naturally yum need sudo access. So I run the script via:

```
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

But the script ends up changing my user to root after it's done. This is an issue for me, because I want the end of the script to add the user running it to the Docker usergroup via:

```
groupadd docker
gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

So by the time the script finishes, it adds root to the group instead of the current user - I imagine this is because I run it with sudo.

Is it possible to sudo run a script but retain the current user's login? From what I understand it's generally not a good idea to use sudo within scripts.

Here's the script (edited after answers below):

```
#!/bin/bash

yum remove docker \
                  docker-common \
                  container-selinux \
                  docker-selinux \
                  docker-engine

yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo


yum makecache fast
yum install docker-ce

systemctl start docker

groupadd docker
groupadd docker
gpasswd -a "${SUDO_USER}" docker
su "${SUDO_USER}" -c "newgrp docker"
```

Comment: `$USER` is environment variable it displays the current user, so you're right, this is because `sudo`. To test , try `sudo echo $USER` and `echo $USER` and see the difference.

Comment: @fugitive `sudo echo $USER` expands `USER` before calling `sudo`. You would need s`udo bash -c 'echo ${USER}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `SUDO_USER` variable to determine whether the script is being run *via* `sudo`, and if so, which user ran it. Then you’d just use that in `gpasswd`:

```
gpasswd -a "${SUDO_USER}" docker
```

or

```
gpasswd -a "${SUDO_USER-$USER}" docker
```

if you want to fall back to `USER` in the absence of `SUDO_USER`.

The command which causes you to end up logged in as `root` (strictly speaking, this doesn’t change your login, it runs a new shell) is

```
newgrp docker
```

To fix that, *i.e.* end up as yourself with `docker` as your primary group, you need to run that as yourself; assuming `sudo`,

```
su "${SUDO_USER}" -c "newgrp docker"
```

will do this.

Note that ending your script with `newgrp` in this way means that your script doesn’t end as such when you get a new prompt; the result is

- the shell you’re in when you type `sudo ./myscript.sh`

  - `sudo`

    - the shell running `myscript.sh`

      - `newgrp`

        - the shell started with `docker` as the primary group

The script will only exit when you exit the shell started by `newgrp`.

Comment: OK, that `newgrp` is a significant element which wasn’t mentioned initially ;-). See my updated answer.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that. I put it in there because I was aiming to [use docker without sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo), and it mentioned that newgrp can be used rather than logging out. I'm mainly looking for a way to not have to exit the shell window I'm using once my user is added to the docker group.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the following output after adding the new 'newgrp' command (though it appears I am still able to execute Docker commands:  


`bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell`

Answer (score 2):

If using sudo at all is generally considered a good practice, and if using it -- especially within a short script meant to be executed manually -- simplifies logic or maintenance and achieves the desired goal, then I would say use of sudo within a script is appropriate, if not preferable.

It is possible to use sudo inside the script, and run the script as a normal user. The invoked sudo will normally ask for a password, just once (or not at all if the user has recently used sudo). However, for proper behavior the script should prevent a user from running it as root.

```
# This should not be run as root (or using 'sudo')
if [ "$(/usr/bin/id -u)" == "0" ] ; then
   echo "This script cannot be run as root (or using 'sudo')!" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
# Use sudo per command here
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

Here, since the $USER variable corresponds to the normal user, it would be inserted as the expected argument for gpasswd.

This example would be run as a normal user; not sudo. Note however, the user must have sudo privileges for it to execute properly.